# Проблема с регистрацией в Yii2

Tags: yii2, регистрация

Поставил на виртуальную машину чистую advanced версию Yii2.
Установил расширение yii2-admin через composer.
Создал подключение к БД Oracle которая лежит на сервере. Для того что бы удостоверится в подключении сделал через gii вывод таблицы пользователей, все отображается, все хорошо.
Далее по [ДАННОЙ ИНСТРУКЦИИ](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-prostaya-realizaciya-rbac-s-dvumya-rolyami.html) проделал все пункты по очереди.
Теперь нужно добавить нового пользователя в БД. На сайте нажимаю кнопку "Регистрация", ввожу нужные данные и получаю вот такую вот ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Подскажите в чем проблема? Дайте пожалуйста конкретный пошаговый урок как реализовать регистрацию/вход/выход пользователями с разными привилегиями. Желательно на русском языке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По видимому та инструкция устарела, так как была опубликована в 2014 году. На сайте в [официальной документации](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs-ru/guide-security-authorization.html) написано что и как сделать. Документация обновляется при изменении чего либо.